Is there a current, widely familiar equivalent of "Irish bull"?
Gardner, The Annotated Alice:

Closely related to Carroll's inversion humor is his humor of logical contradiction. The Red Queen knows of a hill so large that, compared to it, this hill is a valley; dry biscuits are eaten to quench thirst; a messenger whispers by shouting; Alice runs as fast as she can to stay in the same place. It is not surprising to learn that Carroll was fond of the Irish bull, of which logical contradiction is the essence. He once wrote to his sister: "Please analyze logically the following piece of reasoning: Little Girl: 'I'm so glad I don't like asparagus.' Friend: 'Why, my dear?' Little Girl: 'Because if I did like it, I should have to eat it —- and I can't bear it!' " One of Carroll's acquaintances recalled hearing him speak about a friend he knew whose feet were so big that he had to put his trousers on over his head.

Or from The Simpsons:

Homer: Mr. Burns, you're the richest man I know!
Burns: Oh yes, but I'd trade it all for a little more.

"Irish bull" is musty and Oxbridgean enough to require explanation. I sometimes use "headscratcher," but wonder if I'm overlooking something more obvious.

I would add "She will regret it till the day she dies, if she lives that long!" and "Childlessness is hereditary in our family".  Generally, the absurd statement goes unrecognized as such by its author.

If you know what "Irish bull" means, you should say so in your question; if you don't, you should Google it.

@StuartF It seems like he understands it from the context of the Gardner quote, but is looking for another term that would be more familiar to others. Not unreasonable, as I'd never heard the term before.

The OED adds that Irish bull is “now likely to be considered offensive.”

It is often categorised under "surrealism."

There’s an old joke about a tourist lost in the West of Ireland asking a local farmer for directions to Dublin. He replies: ‘Well, if I were you, I wouldn’t start from here’. Well, that's the archetypal "Irish bull" to me. Defined by the (paywalled) full OED as A statement which is manifestly self-contradictory or inconsistent, esp. to humorous effect.

Inspired by @Greybeard comment : surreal incongruity

Besides the fact that "headscratcher" makes evident, that is, according to the Merriam-Webster dictionary, the fact that "something […] is confusing, mysterious, or hard to understand", there is to be considered first and foremost the fact that stems directly from the definition of "Irish bull", or "bull", as it is often written, and which, by the way, is a synonymous equivalent.

(SOED) bull 1 An expression containing a contradiction in terms or implying a ludicrous inconsistency. Often more fully Irish bull.

Note that "Irish bull" is not an entry in the SOED.
It is perhaps worth noting also that "bull", or "Irish bull" as an expression taken in the context of the question (sense 1), is not to be associated with the word "bullshit", as surprising as that may be, (SOED, etymology: [Orig unkn. In senses 3, 4 usu. assoc. w. synonymous bullshit). This is borne out by the Wikipedia article on the term "Irish bull".

(Wikipedia) The derivation of "bull" in this sense is unclear. It may be related to Old French boul "fraud, deceit, trickery", Icelandic bull "nonsense", Middle English bull "falsehood", or the verb bull "befool, mock, cheat".

Threrefore, what is put to the test of someone's reasoning power, when one is talking of Irish bull, is a piece of nonsense, and the reasoning is invariably an explanation of why what you are given to read or what you hear is nonsense. A fully descriptive expression should take that into account, and a term such as "unravelling of conundrums leading to specious arguments" seems to come closer to an ultimate definition. A shorter expression meaning the same thing is probably missing in the language.

But "Irish bull" is a separate entry in the full OED, linked to by one of the subdefinitions for plain "bull": 2.a. 1640– A self-contradictory proposition; in modern use, an expression containing a manifest contradiction in terms or involving a ludicrous inconsistency unperceived by the speaker. Cf. Irish bull n.

@FumbleFingers "Unperceived by the speaker" is a notable addition.

No - that's in the FOED definition for "bull" as cited in my comment under your answer here. It's not present in the specific definition for "Irish bull" that I cited in a comment under the question itself. In that one, esp. to humorous effect strongly implies the speaker does appreciate the paradoxical / oxymoronic element in what he says.

You might ask if the defining characteristic here is the overall contradiction, or the fact that the reader is led down one path only to encounter a twist at the end. If the latter, you could consider it comedic irony -- "...a form of humor that arises from a discrepancy between expectations and reality."  (From fiveable)
